# Find and Replace many Items with Powershell from Data within a CSV, XLS or two txt documents

Tags: csv, powershell, replace

So I recently have found the need to do a find and replace of mutliple items within a XML document. Currently I have found the code below which will allow me to do multiple find and replaces but these are hard coded within the powershell.

```
(get-content c:\temp\report2.xml) | foreach-object {$_ -replace "192.168.1.1", "Server1"} | foreach-object {$_ -replace "192.168.1.20", "RandomServername"} | set-content c:\temp\report3.xml
```

Ideally instead of hard coding the value I would like to find and replace from a list, ideally in a CSV or and XLSX. Maybe two txt file would be easier.

If it was from a CSV it could grab the value to find from A1 and the value to replace it with from B1 and keep looping down until the values are empty.

I understand I would have to use the get-content and the for each command I was just wondering if this was possible and how to go about it/ if anybody could help  me.

Thanks in advance.

SG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#next line is to clear output file
$null > c:\temp\report3.xml
$replacers = Import-Csv c:\temp\replaceSource.csv
gc c:\temp\aip.xml | ForEach-Object {
   $output = $_
   foreach ($r in $replacers) {
      $output = $output -replace $r.ReplaceWhat, $r.ReplaceTo 
   }
   #the output has to be appended, not to rewrite everything
   return $output | Out-File c:\temp\report3.xml -Append
}
```

Content of replaceSource.csv looks like:

```
ReplaceWhat,ReplaceTo
192.168.1.1,server1
192.168.1.20,SERVER2
```

Note the headers

Comment: Hi, on the surface this looks fine, really good bit of code, in testing however I seem to be struggeling with it. I have edited your code slightly to put it out to an xml 
$replacers = Import-Csv c:\temp\replaceSource.csv
gc c:\temp\aip.xml | ForEach-Object {
    foreach ($r in $replacers) {
        $output = $_ -replace $r.ReplaceWhat, $r.ReplaceTo
    }
    return $output | Out-File c:\temp\report3.xml
}
The thing is it only changes the last one on the CSV, it works but only for the last cell, was wondering if you knew why this was. Thanks and great work! :)